# Can't load TeX Live Database during install

Tags: texlive, installing

Currently, I have downloaded Tex live from  [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) but I encounter a problem while installing it. Here is the problem

> "Couldn't load remote Tex Live Database. Please go back and select different mirror"

If you have to know, I'm from Ethiopia.

So, what do you recommend?

Comment: What OS do you use? If you're on Linux, use your distribution's package.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: It is Windows 7.

Comment: Can you try installing it from [dvd](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html)? NB: **don't** forget to check sha256sum of the iso image before burning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you tried... er... going back and selecting a different mirror?